# How to get date and time from string?

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with the following schema:

```
  root

  |-- date : string (nullable = true)
```

The value looks like `201605250000`. How can I extract date, hour and mm from this string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parse string:

```
val unix = unix_timestamp($"date", "yyyyMMddHHmm").alias("unix")
```

Convert to timestmap:

```
val ts = unix.cast("timestamp").alias("ts")
```

Cast to `date` to get a date:

```
val dt = ts.cast("date").alias("dt")
```

Use `hour` / `minute` to get time:

```
val h = hour(ts).alias("h")
val m = minute(ts).alias("m")
```

Example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq((1L, "201605250000")).toDF("id", "date")
df.select($"*", unix, ts, dt, h, m).show

// +---+------------+----------+--------------------+----------+---+---+
// | id|        date|      unix|                  ts|        dt|  h|  m|
// +---+------------+----------+--------------------+----------+---+---+
// |  1|201605250000|1464127200|2016-05-25 00:00:...|2016-05-25|  0|  0|
// +---+------------+----------+--------------------+----------+---+---+
```

**Note**: For 1.5 use `unix.cast("double").cast("timestamp")`